# Using Logic-Analyzer to reverse-engineer ISM-band ASK/OOK encoding, possible?

Tags: rf, oscilloscope, measurement, timing, logic-analyzer

Is it possible to use a Logic Analyzer (such as [this one](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/open-workbench-logic-sniffer-p-612.html?cPath=174)), to determine the waveform s.t. on the DATA out pin of an ISM-band ASK/OOK (315/433.92MHz) RF module, in turn to decode it's encoding scheme. I know for sure that it is not Manchester/NRZ. By 'waveform', I mean the highs/lows with the duration of every bit

Note that this questions is an extension of my [other thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21807/choosing-a-dso-advice-sought) on choosing a DSO. While I might still go in for a DSO, but I really wanted to thoroughly understand the LA as an option for my purpose.

Now for the other (possibly dumb) question -- will a logic-analyzer work without a clock input ? Say in my case of decoding ASK/OOK encoded data, I have no way to retrieve the clock, as this is asynchronous operation.

Query extension (Nov 9, 2011):
My target RF encoder's encoded pattern uses 32 oscillation cycles to encode every bit. So for 9600baud, I have 307200 sample/sec. However, for better accuracy, it might be good to use 3x-5x that many no. of samples (does this concept apply for Logic Analyzers as well) ? If that is true, then for 5x sampling, I'd need 1536000 (~1.5Ms/s), on a single channel. Of course, this reasoning for (kind-of over-)sampling comes from the DSO world, but not sure if it applies for Logic-Analyzers as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did exactly that in a previous project, I didn't use the open logic analyzer but the bus pirate which uses the same software.

http://s3cu14r.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/basic-rf-sniffing-with-the-bus-pirate/

I used this to decode the protocol for another project that sniffed RKE data.

http://hackaday.com/2009/10/03/garage-door-packet-sniffer/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @s3c. That's very interesting & reassuring. I think I did come accross this project earlier, completely missed the part about using Logic-Analyzer. Would you happen to know what kind of buffer was used by James to ampilfy the RF RX DATA out signals ?

Comment: The HAD author screwed up that part completely in the post, I was using the pickit logic analyzer at that point which had a low input impedance that pulled the signal low. If you're using a real logic analyzer or the bus pirate you won't have any of those problems. (It was a simple voltage follower with MCP6001 in case you're still wondering)

Comment: Good to know that (& a relief, since I'd gone ahead and ordered the LA). Thanks for taking time to answer @s3c. I have edited my question slightly to extend it. If you happen to have some thoughts to share around that part, would be great to hear.

Comment: @s3c, cool project!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the added part of your question:

Yes, the sampling rate applies to logic analysers too. Obviously the signal state will be accurately represented as it can only be 0 or 1 (unlike a DSO), but the higher the sampling rate the more accurate the timing.
For instance if you have the following:
Data:
`__---_-____---____---_-____---____`
LA Sample clock:
`--__--__--__--__--__--__--__--__--`
LA Display:
`____----____----____----____----__`

If we assume the logic analyser samples on the rising edge of the clock, you can see how it can get the timing slightly out or miss a change altogether.
You will never miss a change providing the sample rate is at least twice the data rate, but the actual timing of the changes will be less and less accurate as you approach this point.
In your case, the LA you link to will easily cope with a 300kHz toggle rate, as it's sampling at up to 200Msps, which will give you accuracy to +/- 5ns. Since the data only changes every 3.3us or so, the logic analyser will be very accurate as it can sample 666 times during this period.

Comment: Thanks @oli-glaser for the lucid explanation. Pretty clear, on that the sampling rate plays. Re: "LS Sample clock", is this LA's internal clock that drives the sampling ?

Answer (score 0):

The sampling rate used for digital signals depends on the data rate as well as duty cycle, for example, let's say you have a 1khz data signal with 50% duty cycle, sampling at 2khz or over will give reliable results since you only need to check on both sides of the transition.

Now if you have a 1khz data signal with a 10% duty cycle you need to sample at at least 10khz to ensure you get every part of the waveform. With digital signals like these the sampling rate hardly matters since you'll probably just have it set up with an interrupt anyway. The only place it is important is when using a logic analyzer and in this case you can just use auto or try it a couple of times.